# Unicode First, Previous, Next, and Last

Tags: unicode

Unicode has snowmen and chess pieces. Does it have the first (<< or |<), previous (<), next (>) and last (>> or >|) symbols? Those would be quite useful for site navigation between articles and the like.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it has **«** (0x00AB) and **»** (0x00BB)

or maybe these:

- ⇤ (first 0x21E4)
- ← (prev 0x2190)
- → (next 0x2192)
- ⇥ (last 0x21E5)

Answer (score 16):

You also have these options:

- ⏮ (0x23EE)
- ⏪ (0x23EA)
- ◄ (0x25C4)
- ► (0x25BA)
- ⏩ (0x23E9)
- ⏭ (0x23ED)

Comment: And `⏴` (#x23F4), `⏵` (#x23F5;)

Answer (score 6):

I like these:
〈 〉

```
.next:before {
  content: '\232a';
}
.prev:before {
  content: '\2329';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

And a [whole slew of arrows](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html).

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any symbols with those exact meanings, so I guess that you have to combine symbols into what you want. Perhaps the arrows 276E and 276F, and the vertical bar 2759 ([PDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf)).

If you are using this on a webpage, you should be a bit restrictive with what characters you use. Not all fonts have the entire unicode character set, and as you know you can never be 100% sure that the page is shown using the font that you want. Perhaps images may be a better choise to get a consistent look.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...

According to [this pdf document](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2190.pdf), you want

U+2190: ← left arrow

U+2192: → right arrow

U+219E: ↞ something like 'first'

U+21A0: ↠ something like 'last'

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be:

- ⟪ `U+27EA`
- ⟨ `U+27E8`
- ⟩ `U+27E9`
- ⟫ `U+27EB`